How do I change hostname after installing?
I am a silly goose.  I did something stupid and updated apache, php, and mysql before i had a chance to upgrade drupal, when I an much older versions.  I had been updating my server and now the newer installed stuff breaks when I tried to uninstall php8 to php7.  Thus, once I saw it was too late, I couldn't revert because it would break those other updates.
I got the novel idea of mysqldumping to a second server and made the unfortunate error of putting into foobar.com/drupal. Because I was incrementally upgrading I didn't want to mess other things up. Then I redumped, re-imported, and then I noticed I can't remove foobar.com/drupal because it is all in the root foobar.com.
How do I remove the subdirectory? It seems I can't find any file when grepping or searching the tables besides some cache tables.
How do I fix this so foobar.com/drupal can become foobar.com?  Drush seems to crash for no reason too as I can't seem to clear cache, unless there is an easy way to drop tables/files to do so?

You need to edit your Apache config file, /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and change the root folder there. DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal. Save and restart apache sudo service apache2 restart

@NoSssweat the problem isn't apache, because the document root is /var/www/html and that is where the Drupal files are.  the sub directory was in /drupal when i fixed everything on a secondary server.  So things are pointing to http://www.foo.com/drupal/... within the site.  Is there a setting I need to change/clear cache/?

Then check web/sites/default/settings.php there might me something there related to the /drupal rewriting.

Update your database
UPDATE `your_database_name`.`your_table_name` SET `field_name` = REPLACE(`field_name`, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE `your_database_name`.`your_table_name` SET `field_name` = REPLACE(`field_name`, 'foobar.com/drupal', 'foobar.com');

Clear your cache
Using the rebuild script. Open settings.php
(/sites/default/settings.php)
in any text editor. Add this line to the end of the file and save it:
$settings[‘rebuild_access’] = TRUE;

After saving visit the next link.
http://www.example.com/core/rebuild.php

In your browser (where www.example.com is your site’s URL).
After a short pause, you should be redirected to the home page of your site, and the cache should be rebuilt.
Open settings.php (/sites/default/settings.php) in a text editor.
Find the line you added with (( $settings[rebuild_access] )) remove this line, and save the file.
